# ListBuilder changes are not reflecting

Tags: 8, entities

I have a NodeEntityListBuilder class with the following in my `buildHeader` function:

```
public function buildHeader()
{
    $header = array(
        'title' => $this->t('Title'),
        'type' => array(
            'data' => $this->t('Content type'),
            'class' => array(RESPONSIVE_PRIORITY_MEDIUM),
        ),
        'author' => array(
            'data' => $this->t('Author'),
            'class' => array(RESPONSIVE_PRIORITY_LOW),
        ),
        'status' => $this->t('Status'),
        'changed' => array(
            'data' => $this->t('Updated'),
            'class' => array(RESPONSIVE_PRIORITY_LOW),
        ),
    );

    return $header + parent::buildHeader();
}
```

I'm trying to makes changes to the headers and no matter what changes I make, it's not reflecting in the admin.

For example, changing **Content type** to **Content Types**.

I've tried to clear the cache by SQL:

```
TRUNCATE cache_config;
TRUNCATE cache_data;
TRUNCATE cache_default;
TRUNCATE cache_discovery;
TRUNCATE cache_entity;
TRUNCATE cache_menu;
TRUNCATE cache_render;
TRUNCATE cache_toolbar;
```

And also tried by the admin panel: **Configuration > Performance > Clear all cache**

Comment: How are you using the class? I.e. what method have you used to replace the node entity type’s list builder class with your custom one? Also what admin page are you expecting to the see difference on?

Comment: @Clive How do I check that? Sorry I'm new to Drupal and this is a project made by someone else.

Comment: You would probably expect to find an implementation of hook_entity_info_alter in the module file. Also if you’re expecting to see the changes at /admin/content, make sure that path isn’t being provided by a View instead of the list builder. Usually the contextual links will help you determine that (if it says “edit view”, it’s a view for example)

Comment: @Clive I don't have anything that implements the hook_entity_info_alter like you mentioned in the module file. In the operations of my `/admin/content`, it's showing up as `Edit` so I don't think it's a view. However, in the DOM of my form, it has the class `views-form`. So should it be my NodeViewBuilder instead of ListBuilder?

Comment: That class suggests it’s a View - go to Admin -> Structure -> Views, edit the Content one, change/add something and save, then pop back to /admin/content and you’ll know for sure

Comment: @Clive Thanks! How do I edit the content of the rows from a view there? At the current moment, the links of my nodes are not redirecting to the right locale.